# Does the game end?

Tags: dont-starve

I know there is a "Day" counter at the top right in-game (as well as seasons), but I am wondering if this can go on indefinitely or is there an "end" to the game?

For example, when you hit day 100 (day 1,000? day 10,000?), does the game end?  Do you win?  Does it continue?

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: I wasn't asking about win conditions.  Not to mention those posts are over a year old and outdated by now.  I was asking specifically if the timer will ever force the game to end by hitting a certain day.

Comment: Closely related, but slightly different. Keep in mind that outdated posts is not a reason to post a new duplicate question though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot end or win the game by surviving for a set length of time. Theoretically, there may be a point where the day counter becomes too big and breaks but, even assuming it uses a short value (16 bits), 65536 or 2^16 days would require a year of constant playtime.

The difficulty of certain events such as hound attacks increases as you play, so eventually that or using up all the resources would make the game impossible.

Comment: Okay so there is no limit on the "Day" timer aside from a programmatic one?

Comment: @Mkalafut That's right. At least, if there is a hard-limit, nobody's reached it yet.